Why is the time complexity of bidirectional bfs still O(V+E)?
I understand that if the branching factor of the graph is b and distance of goal vertex from source is d, then the time complexity is O(b^d).
I also understand why that would be O(b^d/2) using bidirectional breadth first search.
What I don't understand is why the time complexity of bidirectional breadth first search, expressed in V and E is still O(V + E), same of regular breadth first search.

You should ask this sort of theoretical question on [cs.se]

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [cs.se]

@TangentiallyPerpendicular Questions can be on-topic for multiple sites. Algorithm questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Are you talking about best, average or worst case time complexity?

What complexity had you expected instead?

To see why that remains the upper bound, you simply need to construct a pathological example where this search reach that upper bound with a wide variety of values for V and E.
Start with 6 vertices in a line. To the first vertex, attach a large number of vertices. Between those extra vertices, add any number of additional edges.
A bidirectional search starts at vertices 1 and 6. It then moves to vertices 2, 5 and all of the extra ones. It then explores all of the extra edges (only to find that it has been where they are going), and finds vertices 3 and 4. Then and only then does it discover the obvious path.
At this point it has visited every vertex, and every edge. With O(1) work each, for O(V + E) total work. And this configuration allows E to be all of the way up to O(V^2).
